# Jquery Auto Sum

Tags: jquery

Good evening all, Am new in learning `Jquery`, but I have the basic understanding, Now I want to sum up all input in this table before submitting to database, I got the first row of table working but the appended row not working, my append is working, and if I scan my barcode item is showing up in called row but only the calculation part left. What can I do please? Here is my code:

```js
<script>
                     $('tr').mouseup( function() {
                    var price = $('.selling_price').val(); 
                         var quantity = $('.qty').val(); 
                         var disc = $('.discount').val();
            
            var add = (price * quantity).toFixed(2);
            var minus = (add - disc).toFixed(2);
        $('.Total').val(minus);
                         
                         });
                    </script>
```

```html
        <div class="table">
  <table class="table table-responsive" id="mytable">
    <tr>
      <th>Barcode</th>
      <th style="width:400px;">Item Description</th>
      <th>Serial No</th>
      <th style="width:20px;">Quantity</th>
      <th>Unit Price</th>
      <th>Discount</th>
      <th>Total Amount</th>
      <th colspan="2">Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <!-- pass `this` here -->
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="barcode" id="barcode" placeholder="barcode" onkeyup="showproduct(this.value ,this)">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pname" name="pname" placeholder="Enter item Description">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control " id="serialnumber" name="serialnumber" placeholder="S/N">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="form-control text-center qty" id="qty" name="qty" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="form-control text-center selling_price" id="selling_price" name="selling_price" placeholder="RM0.00" readonly>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" class="form-control text-center discount" id="discount" name="discount" placeholder="RM0.00">
      </td>
      <td>
       <input type="number" class="form-control text-center Total" id="Total" placeholder="RM0.00"  readonly>
      </td>
      <td><button class="btn btn-primary" id="addbtn" type="button"><i class="far fa-plus-square"></i></button></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  </div>
```

```html
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-8">          
    <!-- Button Record Invoice -->
                            <div class="quickinvoice-btn">  
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="quickinvoice" value="quickinvoice">
  Record Invoice
</button></div>                 
</div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <div class="col-md-10">
    <label for="Tax" class="form-label">Sales Tax</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Tax" placeholder="6%">
  </div>
                            
                                        <div class="col-md-10">
    <label for="freight" class="form-label">Frieght Charges</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="freight" placeholder="RM0.00" disabled>
                            </div>
                            
                                        <div class="col-md-10">
    <label for="Subtotal" class="form-label">Sub Total</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control Subtotal"  id="Subtotal" placeholder="RM0.00" disabled>
                            </div>
                </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to calculate, it is not very clear from your comment.

Comment: Am trying to calculate, when you key in the barcode and item is displayed, price * qty to give Total,  then adding Tax and freight charges to give subtotal. i was able to do price * qty to give total, but in my appended row, its not working, only on first table row.